# How to use jquery to create php session using checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, session

I am trying to create a session in php every time a checkbox is selected. i have got this working on each individual check box using the following:

```
onchange="$.get(\'set_item.php?stockID='.$row[stockID].'&push=\'+this.checked);"
```

I now would like to add a check all link which then selects all of the check boxes and then actions the above line to create the php session... so far i have got the check all link working but i can not get the loop to work.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

$('#selectChb').click(function(){ 
     $(':checkbox').prop("checked", true);
});

$(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
    str = this.val();
    $.get('set_item.php?stockID='+str+'&push='+this.checked);
});

$(":checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    str = this.val();
    $.get('set_item.php?stockID='+str+'&push='+this.checked);
});

});
```

Comment: I think you should put this code on the "onChange" event of the element checkbox, not in the document ready.

Comment: What you can do is put your `(":checkbox:checked").each` function into another function and call that function each time your checkbox is checked or rather have it check all on a button click.

Comment: Are you sure that you're actually creating a new session each time you check a box? That doesn't sound particularly practical.

Answer (score 0):

This should allow you to also remove the inline `onchange` that you have on your checkbox elements.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#selectChb').click(function(){ 
        $(':checkbox').prop("checked", true);
    });

    $(":checkbox").on("change", function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            str = $(this).val();
            $.get('set_item.php?stockID='+str+'&push='+this.checked);
        }
    });
});
```